# VPN into windows server 2012 with macOS Sierra

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2, macos-sierra

Is there a way to VPN into Windows Server 2012 with a macOS Sierra.

The office uses PPTP to allow users to VPN into the server to access the drives etc. However macOS Sierra had gotten rid of PPTP VPN.

Is there an easy way to handle this operation? Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Are there third-party clients that allow PPTP connections from MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing VPN, which grants you access to the network that the windows server you want to access is located in, and the actual protocol you use to remote in to the server. This will most likely be RDP.

While I do really want to mention that nowadays you should *never*, ever use PPTP, I see two options:

- you set up a virtual machine on your mac with an operating system that still supports PPTP
- you ask your network administrator to NAT a port of one of your offices public IPs to the RDP port of the windows server you want to access. If your office has a public IP that is reachable on contoso.com, they could set up a NAT rule that forwards, for example, `contoso.com:4444` to `your-windows-server:389`. You could use this FQDN in your RDP session on your mac.

Answer (score -2):

You should have to get a [MAC VPN](https://www.usavpn.com/best-vpn-for-mac/). Just connect it and it will handle the rest. Personally, I am using purevpn, its working good.

Comment: I'm not sure you've read the question carefully. OP needs to connect to a specific VPN of his office, he does not want any cover-my-tracks-service that just VPNs him to another country.